# Bring A Running Android App to Foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am designing a testing tool that requires launching another app and then bring back my activity that I was working on to the foreground.
I have been trying to tackle this problem using a receiver but no luck so far.
Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: So you would like to launch an application from a "test application", and then have that "new application" reopen the "test application"? Or are you looking to do something once you reach that "new application"?

Comment: I want to continue testing once I reach that "new application"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to make anything special, than just 
add a post job (with some delay) to your current handler and send an Intent to start your Activity with flag bring to foreground.

Example for clarification:

```
    /*
    * Your code to launch the 3rd party app
     */
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            Intent openMe = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
            openMe.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); //experiment with the flags
            startActivity(openMe);
        }}, 3000);
```

As the docu says, maybe you should use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

You can also store information's inside of the Intent to retrieve later and rebuildt your screen.

Example:

```
intent.putExtra("someStringAsIdentifier", someInformationObject);
```

Inside of you new activity in onCreate you do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    informationObject = extras.getExtra("someStringAsIdentifier");
}
```

See the docs of Intent for more information. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer JacksOnF1re. However there is still a small issue. When ever the post job starts it takes me back to the main screen activity, and I loose my previous screen that I was using. I have used almost all the flags but it shows an error and insist to have the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK which it isn't helping my case.

Comment: Ok in this case, save all the informations which you need for the screen inside of the bundle that you put into the Intent and retrieve it back in on create.